# How to generate random and non duplicate points that fall within a polygon using Python, Numpy, and Shapely?

Tags: python, numpy, gis, geopandas, shapely

I've been using Python, Shapely, Numpy and Geopandas to generate a dot density map. The dot density map points have different colors according to ethnicity, so it allows for understanding overall city demographics.

I've been using some code similar to the function [found in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73230/160467) to generate points that fall within a polygon. The function takes a polygon and an integer (number of people of different ethnicities) and runs a while loop to create random points that fall within that polygon. It uses Numpy `uniform` for this.

Here's what the geodataframe looks like
[image]

Here's the code I run to create the points:

```
pts_per_person = 5
  epsg = 4326 
  seed = 10

  list_of_point_categories = []
  for field in ['white_pop','black_pop','hispanic_pop', 'asian_pop', 'amerindian_pop',  'other_race_pop',   'two_or_more_races_pop']:
    
    ps = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gen_points_in_gdf_polys(geometry = gdf['geometry'], values=gdf[field],
                                points_per_value = pts_per_person, seed=seed))
    ps['ethnicity'] = field
    ps['year'] = i

    list_of_point_categories.append(ps)

  all_points=gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(list_of_point_categories))

  all_points=all_points.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Here are the functions:

```
def gen_random_points_poly(poly, num_points, seed = None):
    """
    Returns a list of N randomly generated points within a polygon. 
    """
    
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    points = []
    i=0
    
    while len(points) < num_points:
        s=RandomState(seed+i) if seed else RandomState(seed)
        random_point = Point([s.uniform(min_x, max_x), s.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
        if random_point.within(poly):
            points.append(random_point)
        i+=1
    return points


def gen_points_in_gdf_polys(geometry, values, points_per_value = None, seed = None):
    """
    Take a GeoSeries of Polygons along with a Series of values and returns randomly generated points within
    these polygons. Optionally takes a "points_per_value" integer which indicates the number of points that 
    should be generated for each 1 value.
    """
    if points_per_value:
        new_values = (values/points_per_value).astype(int)
    else:
        new_values = values

    
    new_values = new_values[new_values>0]
    #print(new_values.size)
    
    if(new_values.size > 0):
        g = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data = {'vals':new_values}, geometry = geometry)
        
        a = g.apply(lambda row: tuple(gen_random_points_poly(row['geometry'], row['vals'], seed)),1)
        b = gpd.GeoSeries(a.apply(pd.Series).stack(), crs = geometry.crs)
        b.name='geometry'
      
        return b
```

But what I found is that I ended up with multiple duplicate points for each ethnicity. The latitude and longitude values were exactly the same.

[image]

Duplicate points were getting stacked on top of each other. I had to change the `s.uniform` line to `random_point = Point([s.uniform(min_x, max_x) + round(random.uniform(.0001, .001),10), s.uniform(min_y, max_y) + round(random.uniform(.0001, .001),10)])` in order to make it truly random. This had the desired effect of spreading the points out more randomly, there were no duplicates.

[image]

But something about this feels a bit hacky, like I'm not using `.uniform` right. Is this the right way to create random points within a polygon?

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Comment: Sorry, the polygon fields are so large that it's really hard to get them in without using thousands of characters

Comment: Check out the guidance on posting a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example); in this case, the problem would work just as well if your shapes were unit squares, right? If you could set us up with code to work directly with your issue you'd see more people jumping in to help :) Good luck!

Comment: Also, just a warning - [numpy no longer guarantees that setting a seed will generate the same data across numpy versions](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html). Instead, save your random data to a file and read it in if you're trying to e.g. preserve results for a scientific work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the first line of the `while` loop in the `gen_random_points_poly()` function. This line reads:

```
 s=RandomState(seed+i) if seed else RandomState(seed)
```

This initializes the random numbers generator at each iteration of the loop. The initialization depends on the value of `seed` (which is fixed) and the value of `i` (which increments at each iteration of the loop). In effect, if you call the function `gen_random_points_poly()` multiple times, then the sequence of points it will generate will be exactly the same each time. This is why the collections of points generated for different ethnicities are exactly the same.

If you want to obtain reproducible results, you can either create the `RandomState` object once, outside the `gen_random_points_poly()` function. Alternatively, you can provide a different seed each time you call this function. In the latter case it is still more efficient to create the `RandomState` object just once, before the `while` loop instead of creating it repeatedly at each iteration.